# "How to fix 'error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1' while installing "SudachiPy" python package?

Tags: python-3.6

I am working in building Japanese NLP sentiment analysis, to tokenise the Japanese sentence we have a package called "SudachiPy".I tried to install it but I am getting error while installing the package. I'm using anaconda in MAC Book pro.

I tried all the steps mentioned in stack overflow by installing following libraries to debug the error.

```
pip3 install python3-dev
```

Also I tried launching an "Ubuntu" instance from AWS and try to install "SudachiPy" but still encountering the same error.

```
pip3 install SudachiPy


Building wheels for collected packages: dartsclone
  Building wheel for dartsclone (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /anaconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/lf/4754h1x94x39xfw_q6c8_ryc0000gn/T/pip-install-st3sqcmm/dartsclone/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/lf/4754h1x94x39xfw_q6c8_ryc0000gn/T/pip-install-st3sqcmm/dartsclone/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/lf/4754h1x94x39xfw_q6c8_ryc0000gn/T/pip-wheel-x8k1ryul --python-tag cp36
       cwd: /private/var/folders/lf/4754h1x94x39xfw_q6c8_ryc0000gn/T/pip-install-st3sqcmm/dartsclone/
  Complete output (25 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/dartsclone
  copying dartsclone/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/dartsclone
  running build_ext
  cythoning dartsclone/_dartsclone.pyx to dartsclone/_dartsclone.cpp
  /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: /private/var/folders/lf/4754h1x94x39xfw_q6c8_ryc0000gn/T/pip-install-st3sqcmm/dartsclone/dartsclone/_dartsclone.pxd
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  warning: dartsclone/_dartsclone.pyx:119:49: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
  warning: dartsclone/_dartsclone.pyx:120:15: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
  building 'dartsclone._dartsclone' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/dartsclone
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/csrc
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/csrc/src
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I./csrc/include -I/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c dartsclone/_dartsclone.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/dartsclone/_dartsclone.o
  warning: include path for stdlibc++ headers not found; pass '-stdlib=libc++' on the command line to use the libc++ standard library instead [-Wstdlibcxx-not-found]
  dartsclone/_dartsclone.cpp:610:10: fatal error: 'ios' file not found


    #include "ios"
               ^~~~~
      1 warning and 1 error generated.
      error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for dartsclone
```

Comment: The dependency `dartsclone` is the package that failed to build.  This appears to be an issue encountered by several other packages built on certain combinations of MacOS and or Xcode.  Workarounds seem to work for some people, but some projects have also changed their setup.py to accommodate.  For instance https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/23424

Answer (score 0):

You need to install some deps before, similar to Linux `build-essential`:

`xcode-select install`

Also, you may need to specify the right compiler, by setting this env. variable:

`CFLAGS='-stdlib=libc++'`